# Registering instances of same type with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have just picked up Simple Injector and all I currently want to do is this:

```
Container.Register<IMessageHandler>(() => new MessageHandlerOne());
Container.Register<IMessageHandler>(() => new MessageHandlerTwo());
```

I'm just trying to register two message handlers, so I can later iterate through them.

To get back these registered instances, this method sounds like it would do the trick.

```
var instances = Container.GetAllInstances<IMessageHandler>();
//why doesn't instances contain both MessageHandlerOne, and MessageHandlerTwo ?
```

Instead this returns back an empty `IEnumerable`.

What am I doing wrong? For something named Simple Injector you would think this would work?  Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do should fail with an exception on the second call to `Container.Register<IMessageHandler>` since the Simple Injector API [clearly differentiates the registration of collections](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections).

In other words, if you want to resolve a collection, you should register a collection:

```
Container.Collection.Register<IMessageHandler>(
    typeof(MessageHandlerOne), 
    typeof(MessageHandlerTwo));
```